# Почему Symbol работает как сложный тип данных?

Tags: javascript, объекты, ссылки, символы

Символ относится к примитивному типу данных. Это значит, что здесь присвоение какого-либо значения осуществляется с помощью копирования.

```js
let a = 10; 
let b = a; //в переменную "b" копируется значение "a"
```

То есть по сути 10 из переменной `a` и переменной `b` - это две разные десятки.

В сложных типах данных присваивается ссылка.

```js
let object = {}; 
let a = object; //в переменную "a" кладется ссылка на тот объект, который держит переменная "object"
```

Тут как бы все понятно. В переменной `а` и `object` просто есть ссылка на один и тот же объект.

Ок, почему тогда если символ - это примитивный тип данных, все работает так?

```js
let a = Symbol("Hello"); 
let b = a; //в переменную b копируется значение a
console.log(a == b); //true
```

Почему `а` и `b` равны друг другу? Символы работают как объекты? Переменная держит ссылку на символ?

Ведь, если бы осуществлялось копирование, `а` и `b` не были бы равны друг другу. Это были бы совершенно разные уникальные символы (хоть и с одним и тем же описанием). А уникальные символы не могут быть равны друг другу.

**Почему это так работает? Почему в данном случае символы равны друг другу?**

Comment: Не понял что вас не устраивает. В вашем первом примере a и b тоже равны друг другу и вас это ничуть не смущает.

Comment: @AlexeyTen везде в интернете написано, что символы уникальны, везде одна и та же фраза, что не бывает одинаковых символов. Но одинаковые символы бывают, и об этом нигде не сказано явно. Они разные только если создаются методом `Symbol()`, и одинаковые, если создаются копированием. Если бы они были вообще уникальными всегда (копировался бы рандом), то их бы было не возможно использовать. Видимо это всё и смущает.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько понимаю, это было бы уже не копирование, если бы они становились разными. И это была бы куда большая неожиданность.

И это сделало бы работу с символами крайне трудной. Например, как бы мы пользовались `for..of` вместе с `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(object1)`, где каждый символ нужно было бы сначала присвоить переменной.

По сути, `let a = Symbol("Hello")` и `let b = a` — это один и тот же тип присваивания. Если при втором происходило бы изменение символа, то и при первом оно должно было бы происходить, что не имело бы смысла. Символьные ключи нельзя было бы копировать из объекта в объект

Можно сказать, что символ это примитив, копируемый по ссылке, но и это трудно продемонстрировать, поскольку символ неизменяем.

Comment: Он наверное и не по ссылке копируется. Создающему методу достаточно структуру создать из уникального или рандомного префикса и строки дескрипшена. А потом просто копировать эти данные цельным куском как число например.